# Could not initialise Stage with Segmentation fault error

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS so please help me with this.

I follow the tutorial to set up Stage and everything was fine until I am trying to use stageros to load an existing world file (also part of the tutorial)

Input:

tuan@tuan-laptop:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_stage/stage$ ./bin/stageros world/willow-erratic.world

Output:

Segmentation fault.

The error message is too simple and do not provide much information for me to debug. Please help.

Thanks very much.

Tuan.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10639/could-not-initialise-stage-with-segmentation-fault-error/) by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on 2011-07-31**:
Thanks very much. I was using Ubuntu 10.04 and the problem is solved when I upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10. I really appreciate your help. Tuan.

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-07-19**:
Can you try it in a debugger (`gdb --args ./bin/stageros world/willow-erratic.world`) and post a backtrace (`bt`) from the segfault?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-19**:
Can you load any other world file? Do you get any output besides "Segmentation Fault"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @Tuan said, upgrading to 10.10 worked, more like cannot reproduce.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0